# How to use async 'ForEach' in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In the ASP.NET Core Web API project, I wrote the following interface. The first request is normal, and the second request will report an error. It should be that I don't know enough about asynchronous programming. I don't know why errors are reported. I hope a friend can give me some advice.

```
[HttpGet("role_claims")]
public async Task<IActionResult> role_claims()
{
    // var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    // var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
    var roles = this.User.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Role).ToList();

    roles.ForEach(async x => {
            MyRole role = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(x.Value);
            IList<Claim> list = await roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            Console.WriteLine($"{x.ValueType} {x.Value} {list.Count}");
            list.ToList().ForEach(x => claims.Add(x));
    });

    return Ok(claims.Select(claim => new { claim.Type, claim.Value }).ToArray());
}
```

The error information is as follows

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
>
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'OnePlan.Conf.IdentityDb'.
>
> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
>
> Object name: 'IdentityDb'.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.IDbContextDependencies.get_StateManager()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContextDependencies.get_StateManager()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext.InitializeStateManager(Boolean standAlone)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()

Comment: And the first time I didn't get the result I wanted, it was empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an impressive amount of problems for such few lines of code.

Starting with calling `ToList()` on an EF.Core (probably?) context, which you should literally never do. The async version takes care of any multi-threaded synchronization between worker threads.

Then that `ForEach` function you're using doesn't support `async` calls, or you'd be awaiting it. What it does instead is run literally nothing, then return your `Ok()` result, then disposes of your context and lastly actually runs your code inside that `ForEach`, way after the context is disposes, hence your problem.

Either use a regular `foreach` over your entity, or write a `ForEachAsync` extension function and await it in your call.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. That's true. When I try to solve it myself, I  use "foreach" instead, and it can work normally. `foreach (var role in roles) {
                var myrole = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role.Value);
                var list = await roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(myrole);
                Console.WriteLine($"{role.ValueType} {role.Value} {list.Count}");
                list.ToList().ForEach(x => claims.Add(x));
            }`